# PayPal API: Invalid request parameter

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get PayPal user basic personal data.
When I pass attributes, it gives me this error:

```
Invalid request parameter: Requested Attributes are incorrect
```

API Docs:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/permissions/GetBasicPersonalData_API_Operation/

My code:

```
function GetBasicPersonalData(){

    $paypal_config = Config::get('paypal');

    $requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope();
    $requestEnvelope->errorLanguage = "en_US";

    $request = new GetBasicPersonalDataRequest();
    $request->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope;

    $request->attributeList = array('http://axschema.org/namePerson/first', 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last', 'http://axschema.org/contact/email');

    $service = new PermissionsService($paypal_config);
    $response = $service->GetBasicPersonalData($request);

    return $response;
}
```

This is how request looks like:

```
PayPal\Types\Perm\GetBasicPersonalDataRequest Object
(
    [requestEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\RequestEnvelope Object
        (
            [detailLevel] => 
            [errorLanguage] => en_US
        )

    [attributeList] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
            [1] => http://axschema.org/namePerson/last
            [2] => http://axschema.org/contact/email
        )

)
```

And response:

```
PayPal\Types\Perm\GetBasicPersonalDataResponse Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2015-05-26T17:27:05.060-07:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => 02023e9639483
            [build] => 2210301
        )

    [response] => PayPal\Types\Perm\PersonalDataList Object
        (
            [personalData] => 
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 580022
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => Invalid request parameter: Requested Attributes are incorrect
                    [exceptionId] => 
                    [parameter] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorParameter Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 
                                    [value] => PersonalAttributeList
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I don't see my mistake here, some help?

Comment: I would try putting the actual values for First, Last, and Email into the attributeList array, rather then links to these values.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new PersonalAttributeList object to hold the array attributes:

```
$personal_attribute = new PersonalAttributeList();
$personal_attribute->attribute = array('http://axschema.org/namePerson/first', 'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last', 'http://axschema.org/contact/email');
$request->attributeList = $persoanl_attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for me:

```
{
    "requestEnvelope": {
        "errorLanguage": "en_US"
    },
    "attributeList": {
        "attribute": [
            "http://axschema.org/contact/postalCode/home"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.